# iPhone 5 restarts after sometime when ever launching the app

Tags: ios, iphone, memory

I have been developing an app for iPhone5 and iPhone6.

The app is running smooth in **iPhone6**

But in **iphone5** after sometime it is restarting the iphone

Has anyone experienced it as it is something related to memory?

Comment: Apps rarely crash the whole hardware. Most likely there is a hardware problem with you iphone5 and it has nothing to do with your app

Comment: You really mean reboot? Not just your app quitting?